# combining pages at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net page and I want to load the contents of another web page and place it in a panel.  This is the kind of thing that you can do with curl, but I need a native c# solution.

Comment: another web page as in "google.com"?  or another web page as in "some html that I have on my server that is located inside another page"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a native HTML method, actually. How about loading the content into an iframe?

Comment: I've seen this done with an iframe but I'm not particularly fond of the way it comes out visually.

Comment: Maybe I need to look into the formatting options for iframes.

Answer (score 2):

If the HTML you are looking at is in your application, migrate it to a User Control and include that where you need access to the other HTML.

If it is from an external site that you don't control, I'd use an iFrame.  How it looks depends more upon how the other sites data is formatted than yours.

Comment: Another option instead of an iframe would be to use Javascript: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm